# Redirect http to https IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to force any users using the calling my website through

> http://www.mysite.com

to route through

> https://www.mysite.com

automatically.

I've added the following markup to my web.config:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
         http:// to https:// rule 
        <rule name="ForceHttpsBilling" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)billing/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I'm getting an message on the type="redirect" line saying:

> Module qualification required

I'm guessing this means that I need to reference an assembly, or the "rewrite" node needs to be under another parent node, but can't figure it out / get an answer from Google.

The project is ASP.Net and is being hosted in IIS7 using .Net 4.0

Comment: Might get better answers on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ - possible duplicate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/28057/1918

Comment: It is a duplicate of that question with the addition of that answer (which as far as I can see is the same answer as I've written above) doesn't work for me.

Comment: the difference is your regular expression pattern

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't spot that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

**Edit:** Just saw that you want ALL requests redirected, so I removed the references to "billing"...

If you want to do it directly in IIS then you need to install the [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: When I add this to my web.config under the <system.webServer><rules> section my site errors with a 500.19 error when loading. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the URL Rewrite Module definitely installed?

Comment: Your are missing `<rules>` before `<rule>`.